# Wrong Android studio preview behavior

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have layout with two layers, background and content (constraint layout and image):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/background_layout">



    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:background="@color/backgroundColor">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:translationY="50dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:elevation="21dp"
        app:cardElevation="21dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/circular_image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It should be like [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NB77B.png).
When I delete that line in CardView

```
    android:elevation="21dp"
```

Preview [says](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgerZ.png) that image is under content but in emulator nothing changes...

Ok, if we add android:elevation and delete app:cardElevation image will be under content-layout in emulator and over that in preview.

My question is what happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

in the MaterialCardView.